# How to and what is the best way to deploy a rails+react app for production, is passenger good enough?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, passenger

What is the best way to deploy a rails app with react for production?

Till now I found phussion passenger is really great which will deploy the ruby app in production on Apache.

But I am using react gem on ruby, do I need anything additional apart from passenger for deploying a Ruby On Rails app with React ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger or any other Rails server should do. I don't think React or React gem really makes any difference.

I'd look at all the typical factors like performance, ease of install, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think the same as well. Just wanted to confirm. Lets see what others say. I personally prefer passenger, been using it since quite a while, but without react, this time I have added react.